# 'sudo env' and 'sudo -i env' show different results

Tags: sudo

When I run `sudo env | grep PATH`, `sudo -s env | grep PATH`, and `sudo -i env | grep PATH` commands in my server, the first two commands show the same result.

However, the last one, `sudo -i env | grep PATH` shows a different PATH value.

Why is this so, and how can I make `sudo`, `sudo -s`, and `sudo -i` commands have the same PATH variable?

I'm on CentOS 7.8.

Any comments, links appreciated!

Comment: So, what does `sudo -i` do exactly? What does the man page say?

Comment: ↑ see `man sudo` if you are unfamiliar with the built-in reference documentation

Answer (score 0):

It probably steams from the `sudo` command.
How are you expanding/defining your `path` variable? In your local user `.profile`? Because if you just enter `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` you will be the root user and thusly use its `.profile`. According to `man sudo`:

```
-i, --login: Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile, .bash_profile or .login will be read by the shell.
-s, --shell: Run the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell specified by the invoking user's password database entry.
```